# Java synonym of JDK

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[java](/questions/tagged/java) and [jdk](/questions/tagged/jdk) are [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms). However:

- [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-7/synonyms) tag page says that [jdk7](/questions/tagged/jdk7) is going to be remapped to [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) (it looks like it is already the case)
- [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-8/synonyms) and [jdk8](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jdk8/synonyms) are not synonyms (yet)

I suppose the [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7)/[jdk7](/questions/tagged/jdk7) case could be made clearer and it would make sense to apply the same logic to [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)/[jdk8](/questions/tagged/jdk8).

ps: I have created a synonym request for java-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's confusing about it? That line describes what will happen if you try to enter the following tags. If you try to enter [java-7.0](/questions/tagged/java-7.0) or [jdk7](/questions/tagged/jdk7), it will be remapped to the [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) tag. The same exact line appears for every tag that has any synonyms attached to it (see the [Java synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms)).

I've gone ahead and approved the [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) ← [jdk8](/questions/tagged/jdk8) synonym.

Comment: Oh... I thought it was saying that, at a later date, one tag will be remapped to the other. My mistake then. Thanks for the java-8 part.